# Joining the queries for different results

Tags: php, sql, oracle, join

I have 3 queries which is taking too much of time to execute and to load the results in a page (slickgrid) and so I want to optimize it into a single query using joins.

Am unable to get the ideas on how to achieve this. Can any of you guide me here on how to get a single query from the below 3 queries.

```
$ikt = $row['2'];
$id = $row['0'];
$record = $row['1'];


$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `plant_records` WHERE IKT = '".$ikt."' AND Record='".$record."'";
$adddetails2    = mysql_query($sql2);
$recorddetails2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($adddetails2);
$num_rows3      = mysql_num_rows($adddetails2);
if($num_rows3 > 0){
    $storeData[$i][] ='Filled';
 }
else{
    $storeData[$i][] ='Not Filled';
 }


$sql5= "SELECT * FROM `plant_overview` WHERE IKT = '".$ikt."' AND ID_Record='".$record."'";
$adddetails5    = mysql_query($sql5);
$recorddetails5 = mysql_fetch_assoc($adddetails5);
$num_rows6      = mysql_num_rows($adddetails5);
if($num_rows6 > 0){
$storeData[$i][] ='Filled';
    }
else{
    $storeData[$i][] ='Notfilled';
}       


$sql3  = "SELECT * FROM `plant_info` WHERE TG_ID = $id and Present != '' ";
$adddetails3    = mysql_query($sql3);
$recorddetails3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($adddetails3);
$num_rows4      = mysql_num_rows($adddetails3);
if($num_rows4 > 0){
    $storeData[$i][] ='Filled';
}
else{
    $storeData[$i][] ='Notfilled';
}   



 Status: listdata[i]['16'],
 Records: listdata[i]['17'],
 Checking: listdata[i]['18'],
```

I need the results in different listdata as I have to show different data based up on there results.

### Edit

Here's my table structures.

master_table

```
ID (int - PK)
Record (varchar)
IKT (varchar)

( The below are refering to the above table <br>
$ikt = $row['2'];
$id = $row['0'];
$record = $row['1'];
)
```

plant_records

```
ID (int - PK)
IKT (varchar)
Record (varchar)<
Student (varchar)
```

- If Record and IKT present in master_table then "filled" otherwise "not filled"

plant_overview

```
ID (int - PK)
IKT (varchar)
ID_Record (varchar)
Subject (varchar)
```

- If ID_Record and IKT present in master_table then "filled" otherwise "not filled"

plant_info

```
ID (int - PK)
TG_ID (int - this is refering to the ID column in master table)<br>
Present (varchar)
result (varchar)
```

- If TG_ID is present in master_table and Present is not empty then "filled" otherwise "not filled"

Question 2 from comments: How am I going to use the data from different listdata

Answer: In slickgrid, i have columns for Plant_Records, Plant_Overview, Plant_Info

based on the data (Filled / Not Filled) I will be showing different images in slickgrid

For example, in Plant_Record column in Slickgrid.. If the value is Filled I will display Image A, if the values is "Not filled" i will display Image B

In Plant_overview column in Slickgrid.. If the value is Filled I will display Image C, if the values is "Not filled" I will display Image D.

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.0+.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Avoid `*` when it came to use in application. It can give you trouble..

Comment: It would be useful to see you schema for these 3 tables

Comment: I assume you have checked that you have useful indexes on the relevant columns

Comment: As your requirement to merge these queries seems to conflict with your comment about needing the results in diffferent `listdata` elements, can you explain how this data will be used once selected from the database.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Thanks for your suggestion in the first comment and I will learn it. I have added the table structures in my question and I have answered your last comment too. Could you please have a look into it.

Comment: You tagged `oracle`. Are you sure you are using an Oracle database? It looks like your are using MySQL, which is another DBMS. (Does mysql_query even allow access to an Oracle DBMS?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is all you want to do check whether matches exist in the tables? You'd do this with `EXISTS` or `IN`.

**With EXISTS clauses:**

```
select 
  id, record, ikt,
  case when exists (select * from plant_records pr where pr.ikt = mt.ikt and pr.record= mt.record)
       then 'Filled' else 'Not filled' end as pr_filled,
  case when exists (select * from plant_overview po where po.ikt = mt.ikt and po.record= mt.record)
       then 'Filled' else 'Not filled' end as po_filled,
  case when exists (select * from plant_info pi where pi.tg_id = mt.id and pi.present <> '')
       then 'Filled' else 'Not filled' end as pi_filled
from master_table mt;
```

**With IN clauses:**

```
select 
  id, record, ikt,
  case when (ikt, record) in (select ikt, record from plant_records)
       then 'Filled' else 'Not filled' end as pr_filled,
  case when (ikt, record) in (select ikt, record from plant_overview)
       then 'Filled' else 'Not filled' end as po_filled,
  case when (id) in (select tg_id from plant_info where present <> '')
       then 'Filled' else 'Not filled' end as pi_filled
from master_table;
```

Add `where id = $id`, if you want this for one row only.

You should have the following indexes:

```
create index idx1 on plant_records (ikt, record);
create index idx2 on plant_overview (ikt, record);
create index idx3 on plant_info (tg_id, present);
create index idx4 on plant_info (present, tg_id);
```

Only either idx3 or idx4 will be used. You can check which and drop the other. (It can of course happen that the DBMS doesn't use any of the indexes. They are just an offer. The DBMS is to decide whether to use them or not.)

Comment: The Exists query is working fine but how to use them in the listdata? Status: listdata[i]['16'],
 Records: listdata[i]['17'],
 Checking: listdata[i]['18'], like this (posted in question itself before..sorry if you missed it).. I want the output of those in each listdata. Any ideas on how to do this

Comment: I worked on it further and it's fine now. Thanks a lot for your help.